# How to remove underline below EditText indicator?

Tags: android

Recently I had to change the EditText indicator color and, after doing that, a weird line started to appear below the indicator. How can I remove that? Code for what I've done is below.

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#4FB6E1">

    <br.com.edsilfer.kiwi.loading.CircularProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:colorLine="#4e2972"/>

    <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifTextView
        android:id="@+id/flying_charizard"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="70dip"
        android:layout_above="@+id/login_cluster"
        android:layout_margin="15dip"
        android:background="@drawable/flying_charizard"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/login_cluster"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
        android:elevation="4dip"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:paddingRight="10dip">

            <include layout="@layout/rsc_util_remove_act_edittext_focus"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="E-mail"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textColor="@color/textSecondary"
                android:textColorHint="@color/textSecondary"
                android:theme="@style/CustomEditText"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:imeOptions="actionGo"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:textColor="@color/textSecondary"
                android:textColorHint="@color/textSecondary"
                android:theme="@style/CustomEditText"/>


            <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonRectangle
                android:id="@+id/login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
                android:background="@color/textSecondary"
                android:text="@string/act_login_login"/>

            <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFlat
                android:id="@+id/register"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:background="@color/textSecondary"
                android:text="@string/act_login_create_account"/>

            <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFlat
                android:id="@+id/forgotPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/textSecondary"
                android:text="@string/act_login_forgot_password"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/copyright"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:alpha="0.7"
                android:text="@string/act_login_copyright"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/textSecondary"
                android:textColorHint="@color/textSecondary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textH4"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifTextView
        android:id="@+id/man_running"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="70dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/man_running"
        android:elevation="1dp"/>

    <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifTextView
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/login_background"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomEditText" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate since I'm not trying to remove the underbar but an extra line that shows up over the underbar. Please, read the description more carrefully

Comment: For material design use app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp" on TextInputLayout.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Make background like this
 `android:background="@null"` of your editText

Comment: Cannot use this solution if you already use a custom background drawable.. :(

Comment: I think if we use a custom background,the line below the edit text will not be visible.

Comment: no i use a custom background drawable. but still have the underline this not work in this situation

Comment: totally agreed, using custom background it is still the underline

Answer (score 70):

If you are using the [material components](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout.java) `TextInputLayout`, setting the background color to something else doesn't remove the underline, the solution is to set the `BoxBackgroundMode` like this (kotlin):
`myTextInputLayout.boxBackgroundMode = TextInputLayout.BOX_BACKGROUND_NONE`

or in xml:
`app:boxBackgroundMode="none"`

I think that this change on the component was made to make the underline 'work' with a custom background color

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! `TextInputLayout layout = new TextInputLayout(context); layout.setBoxStrokeColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); //<-- nope 
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); //<-- nope 
        layout.setBackground(null);//<-- nope 
        layout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.textboxcolor);//<-- nope `

Comment: This is the only true answer. All others are fake.

Comment: Not working for me :/

Comment: Right to the point! Works like a charm :)

Comment: Thanks, it works with material edit text too.

Comment: WOW! of all the workarounds mentioned here, `app:boxBackgroundMode="none"` does the trick with custom background as well! Kudos. For reference I was using a material `TextInputEditText` wrapped by a `TextInputLayout` with androidX

Comment: Nice, well done!

Answer (score 18):

If `android:background="@null"` doesn't help - try to combine it with `android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"`

The full view:

```
    <EditText
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@null"
      android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions" />
```

Answer (score 16):

set the `background` color of `EditText` to white.

You can set the background color of your screen to `EditText` background, if both screen background color and `EditText` background color are same means `EditText` underline won't be visible.

```
android:background="#FFFFFF"
```

Answer (score 15):

Use `edittext.clearComposingText();` before `getText()` or in `.xml` you can use `android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"`

Comment: Line is still there even using that...

Answer (score 8):

android:background="@android:color/transparent"

Answer (score 8):

programmatically I did it this way:

```
editText.setBackground(null);
```

Comment: Also can be done via xml - android:background="@null"

Comment: for me it's editText.setBackgroundColor(null) that works.

Answer (score 1):

You can also define a STYLE for your editText so you can regroup all properties in common. It is very powerful if you have to multiple edit text that need to has the behaviour

Put the code in res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="MyEditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">@color/transparence</item> //NO UNDERBAR
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:height">28dp</item> //COMMON HEIGHT
</style>
```

After that you just need to call it in your editText

```
               <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit1"
                style="@style/MyEditTextStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
               <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit2"
                style="@style/MyEditTextStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`setColorFilter()` does not work on API levels 5 and below. One way is to use `setBackgroundColor(TRANSPARENT color)` & use `clearColorFilter()` to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as shown in the screenshot of the OP. The solutions described in [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37826330/2613692) just remove the underline which you wanted to customize. It would be ok to inherit the **style** from `Widget.AppCompat.EditText` but not **theme**. The fix is to remove inheritance from your CustomEditText:

```
<style name="CustomEditText"><!-- parent removed -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

Credits go to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44036429/2613692)