# Handles of EditText are underlined

Tags: android, android-edittext

I encountered a problem recently, which was to change the default underline bar of an edittext from a default blackish color to white.

I used this solution, which seemed to me the best practices by changing the style of the EditText :

**EditText**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
    android:id="@+id/nom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/Activity_Main_EditText_Nom"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textColorHint="@color/activityBackground"
    android:theme="@style/EditTextStyle"
    android:visibility="gone"
/>
```

**style.xml**

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/activityBackground</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="EditTextStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

It worked ! But it also added to the handles of the EditText an underline bar...

[image: Underlined handlers]

Any ideas ?

---

## **Answer**

By discussing with [@rafsanahmad007](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43468532/4609742), we finally got to a final solution.

**style.xml**

```
<resources>

    <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/activityBackground</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.EditText" parent="MyTheme">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Apply `MyTheme` to application, as usual. When you want to tweak an `EditText` just add to it :

**EditText**

```
<EditText
     ...
     android:theme="@style/MyTheme.EditText"
     ...
/>
```

Comment: You can check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37824790/how-to-remove-underline-below-edittext-indicator

Comment: @visheshchandra Thanks for this link, those handlers/indicators/cursors have so many names I didn't come across this one! Unfortunately, changing the color filter of the EditText brings some problems, like disable the color change from white to colorAccent when it's selected and such.

Comment: General tip: unless you want to subclass `EditText`, you don't need to use `AppCompatEditText`.

Comment: @Sufian True, I was using some `app:` attributes before, so I needed `AppCompatEditText`, but now I may switch back to `EditText`.

Comment: It could be because you're using `android:theme`. Does the handles' underline go away if you set `style` instead of `android:theme`?

Comment: @Sufian They does go away, but the EditText's underline is not white anymore. Same problem with Rafsanahmad007's answer below.

Comment: @QuentinBeuvelet does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40889531/1276636) help?

Comment: @Sufian Nope, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with your style themes.. parent

use below code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
    android:theme="@style/MyStyle.EditText"/>
```

Now in your styles.xml

```
 <style name="MyStyle.EditText">
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/MyEditTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyEditTextStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

try not to use the theme parent directly

**EDIT**

add the color property in base theme also

```
 <style name="Theme.App.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

make sure you select the theme in your activity in manifest...

Comment: The handles' underline have disappeared, but the EditText's underline is not white when not selected. Did I miss something ?

Comment: use `editText.getBackground().setColorFilter(R.color.white, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);`...for the underline color..

Comment: Setting the ColorFilter disable the color changing from white to colorAccent when the EditText is selected.

Comment: `colorcontrolNormal` white should work...what api are u testing? i tested it and it works

Comment: `minSdkVersion 15`, `targetSdkVersion 21`, Phone is 23. I added my theme to the question.

Comment: @QuentinBeuvelet i have edited the answer...pls check

Comment: Just by adding the color property to the main theme, it works. However, I find it unfortunate to apply a theme to the entire activity just for an EditText. Well, I think I can live with it, but if you find a better solution, I would be happy to see it!

Comment: #DoublePostOfShame I changed it a little bit and I think I got it. See my edit, and thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Use this doc.I think this URL will helpfull for your problem.

http://www.materialdoc.com/edit-text/

Comment: Thanks for passing by, unfortunately your link doesn't really talk about my problem :/

Comment: Link 404 not found