# EditText underline disable color

Tags: android, colors, android-edittext, underline

My question is - How to change disables `EditText` underline color on 17 API? I 
have tried with styles and didn't look for disabled param. Any suggestions?

Comment: you can check this > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37824790/how-to-remove-underline-below-edittext-indicator

Answer (score 2):

You can set edittext background transprent to remove underline

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37824790/how-to-remove-underline-below-edittext-indicator/37825781)

Below `API level 21`

To set the color:

```
editText.getBackground().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

To remove the color:

```
editText.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
```

> Note: when the EditText has focus on, the color you set won't take
>   effect, instead, it has a focus color.

Comment: Its not sloves my problem. Now underline is grey, i need it white, your solution do not make anything. android:background="@color/white" makes all view white!