# How to remove bottom padding from TextInputLayout

Tags: java, android, kotlin, textinputlayout

The first picture is what I want. The second picture is what I have implemented.
As you can see, there is a padding to the bottom of the TextInputLayout which makes the gray background overflow past edittext line.

Please do not suggest negative margin or padding as it does not work in newer APIs.

Here is the XML I have for the first text input layout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/fullNameTextLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:background="#EAEAEA"
    android:hint="Full Name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fullNameEditText"
        style="@style/Regular15Grey1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:singleLine="true"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture2]

Comment: [It seems to be work if you try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37824790/how-to-remove-underline-below-edittext-indicator/37825781)

Answer (score 4):

I've found the padding is actually space for the error text, if you disable the error (e.g. in the layout XML with `app:errorEnabled="false"`) the padding is closer to what you'd expect.

Answer (score 3):

You can using `android:layout_marginBottom="-xdp"` in your EditText

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fullNameEditText"
        style="@style/Regular15Grey1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-xdp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:singleLine="true"/>
```

value of x depend on your design.

hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullNameTextLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:hint="Full Name"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fullNameEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:text=""
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-8dp"
            android:singleLine="true"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add a `2dp line` below the `EditText`

```
<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />
```

You can change the color and the width later